# How do I create a secure clamping circuit?

Tags: diodes, zener, schottky, diode-clamp, clamp

Clamping is good for transients, e.g voltage peaks. But two issues with clamping is that if you have a linear voltage regulator attached to 3.3v and 3.3v is the voltage regulator output, then that voltage might going to increase.

The other issue with clamping is that if the voltage is negative, then we are going to have negative voltage after the lower schottky diode.

Have a look att this picture.

**Question 1:**
How can I prevent so 3.3v will not increase(in practice) if I'm using a linear voltage regulator and 3.3v is the linear voltage regulator outut for e.g a microcontroller?

**Question 2:**

How can I prevent so negative voltage will not appear at the round blue circle? Assume that this is an digital input for a microcontroller. When I apply 24V, then i'm going to have a 1 as digital input. But if I'm applying -24V, then the digital input going to recieve vaccum and become destroyed. Why?

Picture shows 10K resistor and 2 schottky diodes as a transient and high voltage(30V) protection.

[image]

Comment: If you plan to use 24VDC signals, then make a resistor divider, or use a zener diode instead of both diodes. The MCu input more likely will survive a small negative voltage, link the datasheet of the MCU.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič No, I'm going use from 3.3v to 30V signals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequent issue: for example opamps driving and ADC and pumping the 3.3V line up so something else. Today's opamps are *strong*.

A zener diode saves the day, as for question one. It simply dissipates the voltage excess. You have to do some balancing for tolerances but it works fine.

Case number two is trickier. *Usually* you simply try to minimize the voltage and current in the ESD diodes. For example, most of the time you have an *absolute* of -0.3V to VCC+0.3V in ratings. That works well with schottky diodes. Also if you keep the fault current to less than 1mA they can usually sustain it without issues. There is some useful information in the old microchip TB3013 application note

Comment: Today, I'm using a zener diode, but some one told me that zener diode is a bad idea beacuse zeners are slower than schottky diodes.

Comment: How would you do this circuit? http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Answer (score 1):

Note that a GPIO has a specification of max applied voltage and max. current. By voltage it means that you apply an ideal voltage source, like lab PSU and then the GPIO will survive -0.3< V < Vcc+0.3V. On the other hand you have a max. current of let's say (you didn't specified the MCU) 5mA. Now the GPIO already has those two diodes inside, so you limit the current with a resistor.

30V/10k = 3ma, is just enough to limit below limit.

Let we have a 10k, 3.6V zener and 100R resistor. Then we swap the 24V polarity:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa3Wsu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using Thevenin, we end with this equivalent circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH4M9R.png)</sup>

We can do the same with correct polarity 24V connected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD2XBH.png)</sup>

A small cap will limit the dV/dt just enough that a zener can activate.

EDIT:

I have expanded the example, with swapped polarity and correct 24V. I used a 3.6V zener MMBZ5227BLT1G and omitted the voltage drop in internal GPIO protection diodes.  <strike>From above results you can see that a zener of 3.6V is not suitable, because the max current into a GPIO would be 6.3mA. So I suggest you to use a 3.3V zener instead.</strike>

Comment: So you mean that the 100nF cap will handle peaks?

Comment: And reverse current?